# Firestore unable to access data - Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Problem:**

Firestore not returning data and giving exception "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions"

**Rules:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Android Code:**

```
firestore.collection("todos").document("t2").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "E1:" + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });
```

**Database:**

[image]

**Working:**

1. Firebase authentication is working fine.
2. Firebase Realtime Database is also working fine.

**Things I tried:**

1. It says firestore rule can take some time to take effect, so I waited around 24 hours but still no result.
2. I tried rules playground and it says data is readable
   [image]
3. Tried creating new android app and adding in project, still same problem with new app.

Please tell me what I might be missing. As firebase google authentication is working fine, I can say my app is communicating with firebase and SHA-1 is also right. I found other similar questions too, but all says to change rules, which already flexible as possible. I know my rules are insecure, I just want to communicate with database to make sure everything is right.

Comment: firebase version?

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0

Comment: Most likely is that your app is trying to access a different project. I'd recommend redownloading the `google-services.json` and adding it to your app again.

Comment: I just created a fresh app and downloaded google-services.json for that app, but new app still getting same issue.

Comment: I checked my google-services.json file too and project_id is same as shown in my console

Comment: I tried to compare my google-services.json with my old project where firestore was working, I found some stuff, I don't know if these are relevant: firebase_url is missing, client type is 3 in this project's google-services.json and missing android_info, certificate_hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after wasting several hours, creating multiple projects and multiple apps, my problem got solved, and solution is very weird.

Google account on which I was creating these projects was relatively new and even though I was creating new projects I was getting same results. Then I created project using my old Google account which I used in past for firebase, and it started working fine.

I don't know why this happened. I don't think reason is related to bank verification because my project was just started and in free tier, and all other features were working fine. May be this was bug in firebase.